# Make JavaFx application Fullscreen OnClick

Tags: javafx

Hello i am making a web browser in javafx and i want to make it fullscreen when user clicks on Fullscreen button. I tried the below given code but unfortunately it is giving error.

```
Fullscreen.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
  @Override
 public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
   primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);   // here it gives error "cannot find variable primaryStage"
 } 
});
```

**I know that this doesn't follow the basics of java but i didn't find another way of implementing it.
Kindly help :)

Comment: Are you serious? Java basics? I think you might want to store your `Stage` object somewhere so you can access it later on..

Comment: Sir i want to know the way of doing it. Obviously there is no way to store objects.

Comment: Here you go: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Fullscreen is a button, just get the stage it's in with

```
((Stage)Fullscreen.getScene().getWindow()).setFullScreen(true);
```